Splitting Scalar into Holomorphic and Anti-Holomorphic Parts
I am reading Tong’s string theory lecture notes. On page 78, he splits the 2d free scalar into left- and right-moving parts, seemingly using the classical equation of motion as justification.
Why is he able to do this? I thought that the classical equations of motion only hold on the mass shell. Certainly it’s true that not every free scalar satisfies the Klein-Gordon equation. Is there an implicit assumption of being on-shell in his argument? If this is the case, are there any resources for off-shell CFT that can derive the same results of the spectrum, stress tensor, etc. without this assumption?
If this ability to split into left- and right-movers is manifest, why would that be the case?

In  the Heisenberg picture the  field operators satisfy the equation of motion, and that is how the usual decomposition is made.
In a Euclidean path integral formulation, one  can follow Mandelstam and define an off shell decomposition
$$
\phi_R(x,y)= \frac 12 \phi(x,y )+ \frac i 2 \int_{-\infty}^x \partial_y \phi(x,y) dx,
$$
which makes the no-locality of the decomposotion manifest. (In real-time there would be no $i$). This follows from writing
$$
\phi(z,\bar z)= \int_{-\infty}^z \partial_z \phi(z,\bar z) dz+ \int_{-\infty}^\bar z \partial_{\bar z} \phi(z,\bar z) d\bar z
$$
and recalling that
$$
\partial_z = \frac 12(\partial_x-i\partial_y), \quad etc.
$$


Tong is here using the operator formalism, which is manifestly on-shell. In the Heisenberg picture, the Heisenberg EOMs are operator identities, cf. answer by mike stone.

In contrast, the path integral formalism is off-shell.


See also e.g. this Phys.SE post.
